# SOAP UI - ERROR:Exception in request: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: ssl, soap, soapui

I am trying to hit the third party webservice using SOAP UI and getting below exception:

> ERROR:Exception in request: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

I dont have cacert or keystore from the third party webservice but I have signature.By using signature I'm able to hit the third party webservice through my application.

How to configure this signature in SOAP UI?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932517/soapui-fails-to-connect-https-sslpeerunverifiedexception

Answer (score 12):

Adding below parameter to C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\SoapUI-5.2.1.vmoptions worked for me.

-Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.2,SSLv3

[Check this link](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/How-to-enable-TLS-1-2-in-SoapUI/td-p/96239/page/2)

Comment: Adding above option in vmoptions worked in 5.3.0. Only thing had to close and restart soapui.

Comment: Update: after updating the vmoptions file access to remote end point worked fine. However, next step for importing site certificate failed. Solution- upgrade to SoapUI 5.5.0 (which is the current latest version as of March 2019) fixed both issues.  Choose option to upgrade the current SoapUI version. If you are upgrading the current version it will install new vmoptions file. (the first issue of ssl handshake is also fixed in 5.5.0, no need of adding parameters for TLS in vmoptions file)

Answer (score 5):

Quick fix: Upgrade to `SoapUI` version 5.4.0. This will fix the SSL handshake issue.

Comment: Had 5.4.0 running without problems, but today got the error on a project that would otherwise run just fine.

Comment: I have 5.4.0 and facing the problem with it .. any thought

Comment: thanku so much...i am new to soap ui and i was struggling with the same since 3 days

Answer (score 3):

After i put below line in file SoapUI-5.2.1.vmoptions. It worked fine for me.

**File Path :** SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\SoapUI-5.2.1.vmoptions

**Add below Line:**

-Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.2,SSLv3

Answer (score 1):

I had 5.5 SOAP UI and calling an gateway API hosted in https URL.
I tried all the java versions , TLS protocol nothing worked for me.

I downloaded the certificate (for me it was truststore.jks) which I was using to connect to API ,  use certificate password ( used to see all the certificates in your ) and check the Check box as shown in image. I am able to make a https connection.

[image: SOAP UI Setup]

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but my solution might help someone.

In SoapUI version 5.3.0 I solved this problem by removing line:

```
if exist "%SOAPUI_HOME%..\jre\bin" goto SET_BUNDLED_JAVA
```

from the `soapui.bat` and then using `soapui.bat` for program execution. It seems that Java embedded with SoapUI is a different version than mine which is JRE 1.8.0_131.

Answer (score 0):

For me, only ssl changes did not work.

Check your

> java version

it may differ from SOAP-UI jre
at his case got to `smartbear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin` directory open `soapui.bat` 
update with compatible java version like:

```
REM set JAVA=%SOAPUI_HOME%..\jre\bin\java 
set JAVA=D:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin\java
```

close the first line with `rem` and update `java` dir.

> run `soapui.bat`

Answer (score -1):

The problem it's the compatibility between your Java installed on your computer and the Java who is used by soap (for me it's SOAPUI-5.5.0)

SOAP UI was not supporting very well the last version installed of Java.

Modify the file soapui.bat in (usualy installed here)

> C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.4.0\bin\soapui.bat

You can see there two lines :

> if exist "%SOAPUI_HOME%..\jre\bin" goto SET_BUNDLED_JAVA
>
> if exist "%JAVA_HOME%" goto SET_SYSTEM_JAVA

First line SoapUi is setting the jre directory to the one in is own folder
Second line SoapUi is saying than if you have java installed, use this one instead.
So you just have to comment the second line like that :

> if exist "%SOAPUI_HOME%..\jre\bin" goto SET_BUNDLED_JAVA
>
> rem if exist "%JAVA_HOME%" goto SET_SYSTEM_JAVA

And for me it's works where whith all other kind of action (permitting TLS1.1 etc) dont.

Comment: This does not work for me.
Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932517/soapui-fails-to-connect-https-sslpeerunverifiedexception