# SoapUI 5.3.0 shows up - Page could not be loaded for HTTPS urls

Tags: oauth-2.0, soapui

I am new to SOAPUI. Using it to test my RESTAPI. I need to add an OAuth2 token in the authentication header. I do the following steps:

1. Click on Get Token
2. In OAuth2 token configuration screen, I enter the authourization and token end points. I am using wso2 Identity server 5.3.0. End points are HTTPS end points.
3. Press on 'get token'.
4. SOAPUI browser dialog pops up showing 'Page could not be loaded'.
5. If I change the end point to a non-https URL, this loads up fine. Tried www.yahoo.com and it loads up fine.

I tried configuring the WSO2 Identity server's JKS file . But did not succeed.

In a nutshell, SOAPUI browser dialog cannot load HTTPS urls. Tried the solution mentioned in the SO post [SoapUI fails to connect HTTPS (SSLPeerUnverifiedException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932517/soapui-fails-to-connect-https-sslpeerunverifiedexception)

Added `-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false` to SOAPUI.vmoptions.
But still no good. I am using JDK 7.

Comment: Could you post the endpoint you use ? Also , does the IS throw any errors?

Comment: Authorization URL : https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize
Access Token URL : https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token

Those are WSO2 Identity Server Endpoints. I even tried adding a public https URL like : https://www.gmail.com but does not work.

Thanks for replying. Hope this helps

Comment: Have you tried `https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authz` as the Authorization URL?

Comment: Yes I tried it. But as I mentioned earlier, SOAPUI browser is not able to load any Https URI. Error message is : Page could not be loaded

Comment: I have the same issue . Did you find any resolution please to the above issue?

Comment: same issue here cant find soluntion, api not alowing not secure redirect url, soap not dealing with local https...