# soapUI - how to set ignore SSL validation?

Tags: ssl, soapui

Hello I need a simple method to ask soapUI to ignore SSL validation when I call an https sevice.
Acuatlly my error is unable to find valid certification path when I import tha wadl.

```
 org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
 sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
 sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
 unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Maybe somethong to set on the SoapUI-5.2.0.vmoptions...?
This is my actual file:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx1000m
-Dsoapui.properties=soapui.properties
-Dsoapui.home=D:\Programmi\soapUI\SoapUI-5.2.0/bin
-Dsoapui.ext.libraries=D:\Programmi\soapUI\SoapUI-5.2.0/bin/ext
-Dsoapui.ext.listeners=D:\Programmi\soapUI\SoapUI-5.2.0/bin/listeners
-Dsoapui.ext.actions=D:\Programmi\soapUI\SoapUI-5.2.0/bin/actions
-Dwsi.dir=D:\Programmi\soapUI\SoapUI-5.2.0/wsi-test-tools
-Djava.library.path=D:\Programmi\soapUI\SoapUI-5.2.0/bin
-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
-splash:SoapUI-Spashscreen.png
-Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true
```

Comment: Please see if any of these answers help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932517/soapui-fails-to-connect-https-sslpeerunverifiedexception

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work. That solution is for a type of https not supported: I need to do the call insecure, equivalent of "--insecure" parameter on the curl.