# Kerberos Authentication with Burp Proxy

Tags: proxy, fiddler, kerberos, burp

I am trying to setup Burp Suite so I can be tamper with HTTP requests and run security vulnerability scans against a .NET application that uses Kerberos for authentication(i.e. windows integrated authentication w/Kerberos support only).  To access the app normally in IE, I add a set of credentials to Windows using Credential Manager, which then uses the credentials during authentication.  I setup Burp Suite and  can see requests/responses they pass through from the browser, however I cannot tamper with requests in Repeater/Scanner because Burp Suite does not update the Authorization header automatically.

I know Fiddler supports Kerberos, so my thought was to chain Burp to Fiddler.  I first made sure I could get tampering to work in Fiddler (using [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/09/04/fiddler-http-401-authentication-workaround-to-support-channel-binding-tokens-removing-endless-prompts.aspx) as a guide).  I then set Fiddler to be Burp's upstream proxy, but when I tampered with a request in Burp I still got a 401 Unauthorized when issuing requests.

Any other ideas on how I could get Burp to do Kerberos Authentication?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it sends the 401 back to Burp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Fiddler's `Rules` > `Automatically Authenticate` menu option, Fiddler will automatically respond to HTTP/401 login challenges using NTLM, Digest, or Negotiate (Kerberos) using the current user's login credentials.

If the login credentials for the site are different, you need to do this:

`Rules` > `Customize Rules`. Scroll to the `OnBeforeRequest` method. Add the following:

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs("targetsite.com"))
{
  // Don't forget to use a double \\ in the string below
  oSession["X-AutoAuth"] = "domain\\user:password";
}
```

Fiddler will use the specified `domain\user` and `password` to respond to `HTTP/401`s from `targetsite.com`.

Comment: Got it working with a few more modifications.  I did what you said above, ensured Fiddler was setup to decrypt the HTTPS traffic coming from Burp(Tools - Fiddler Options - HTTPS - Decrypt Traffic From All Processes), and then I had to start Burp with the commandline option -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true.  I also added Fiddler's certificate to java's trusted certs, but I'm not sure if that actually did anything (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569356/soapui-not-working-with-fiddler-for-rest-service-testing).

Comment: Ok, it's only partially working, but at least it's something.  The app I'm working on authenticates to multiple domains, and apparently something is going screwy with SSL in Burp.  I can issue requests to one domain in Burp, but when I try to issue requests to another I get a "server certificate change is restricted during renegotiation" error.  Sounds like a JVM issue, but can't tell what it is exactly yet

Comment: "server certificate change is restricted during renegotiation" implies that the server (or your intermediaries) is returning different certificates for a single host.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it's fiddler then because right now the request path is Burp(repeater) -> Fiddler -> App (a.app.tld, b.app.tld, etc).  From one instance of Burp I can hit a.app.tld just fine, but if I try to hit b.app.tld it fails with the renegotiation error.  But if I open a new instance of Burp, I can then hit b.app.tld, but then I can no longer hit a.app.tld because of the renegotiation error.