# Fiddler doesn't show http requests from my java backend

Tags: java, http, proxy, fiddler, interceptor

In debug I see following row:
[image: http://joxi.ru/jgmvRJephoNdma]

It is usuall apache http client.

But in fiddler I don't see this request.

I gave read following article [Configure a Java Application to Use Fiddler](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configurejavaapp)

And jvisualvm shows following information:

[image]

In fiddler I see all requests from browser.

How to see request from backend?

### UPDATE

while this row executes I see j`ava.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect` but I think that i anyway should to see attempt to make request

Comment: Is your request HTTPS? Have you configured Java to trust Fiddler's root certificate?

Comment: How can I know whether http or https ? And I didn't configure Fiddler to trust Fiddler's root sertificate.I don't knpw how to make it

Comment: You can know whether you're making a HTTP or HTTPS request by looking at the code. Probably a few lines above the `httpClient.executeMethod` line you show above.

Comment: See this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/22907237/4192895

It worked for me