# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated in SOAPUI tool

Tags: soapui

I am testing a wsdl file using SOAPUI tool(5.0.0 version).
For authentication we are using a certificate.
I have uploaded client certificate under preferences->SSL Settings.
I cheked "none" as proxy settings option in preferences->proxy settings.
With this settings I am able to communicate with service provider, if I try it from home internet connection.

But in my company we use proxy, so I modified proxy settings in preferences->proxy settings option(checked manual radio button and provided host and port values).

If I send the request, I get javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated error.

Could any one help to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

SoapUI doesn't trust the certificate of the proxy. It must be added to the trusted root certs similar to this answer [SoapUI not working with fiddler for REST service testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569356/soapui-not-working-with-fiddler-for-rest-service-testing/22907237#22907237)
But instead of using the Fiddler cert use the certificate of your company proxy server.

Comment: I've tried all the suggestions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932517/soapui-fails-to-connect-https-sslpeerunverifiedexception but none of them worked. I had to set the Proxy Settings in the SOAPUI from "Automatic" to "None" to get it to work. Alternatively you need to add the Proxy Cert to the Key Store as suggested here.